# Cordova 2.7 project can't be compiled

Tags: android, cordova

I have followed the instructions at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android and as per the guide I have a "red x" on my project; I followed the instructions to clean build but nothing changed.

I receive the following 5 errors

```
The import org.apache.cordova cannot be resolved    Bathurst.java   /Bathurst/src/com/aligma/bathurst   line 23 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   Bathurst.java   /Bathurst/src/com/aligma/bathurst   line 25 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Bathurst must override or implement a supertype method  Bathurst.java   /Bathurst/src/com/aligma/bathurst   line 28 Java Problem
DroidGap cannot be resolved to a type   Bathurst.java   /Bathurst/src/com/aligma/bathurst   line 30 Java Problem
Config cannot be resolved   Bathurst.java   /Bathurst/src/com/aligma/bathurst   line 32 Java Problem
```

The generated file with the issues above follows

```
package com.aligma.bathurst;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class Bathurst extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

So that's where I'm stuck at the moment.

In the meantime I managed to build a cordova-2.7.0.jar. In project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, I added this using the "Add External JARs..." button. All the build errors disappeared but I can't run the application.

Looking for ideas as to what I can do next.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the application using Run As > Android Application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries, I added this using the "Add External JARs..." button. All the build errors disappeared but I can't run the application.

Undo that. Put `cordova-2.7.0.jar` in your project's `libs/` directory instead. That will not only add it to your build path, but it will also package the JAR's contents into your APK, which "Add External JARs..." does not.

As to why this JAR was not automatically put in `libs/` for you when you created the project, that I can't answer, as I have not tried 2.7.